# Updating dictionary with randint performing unexpectedly

Tags: python, random, dictionary

I'm trying to run a simple program in which I'm trying to run `random.randint()` in a loop to update a dictionary value but it seems to be working incorrectly. It always seems to be generating the same value.

The program so far is given below. I'm trying to create a uniformly distributed population, but I'm unsure why this isn't working.

```
import random

__author__ = 'navin'

namelist={
"person1":{"age":23,"region":1},
"person2":{"age":24,"region":2},
"person3":{"age":25,"region":0}
}

def testfunction():
    default_val={"age":23,"region":1}
    for i in xrange(100):
        namelist[i]=default_val
    for index in namelist:
        x = random.randint(0, 2)
        namelist[index]['region']=x

    print namelist


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    testfunction()
```

I'm expecting the 103 people to be roughly uniformly distributed across region 0-2, but I'm getting everyone in region 0.

Any idea why this is happening? Have I incorrectly used `randint`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because all your 100 dictionary entries created in the for loop refer to not only the same value, but the **same object**. Thus there are only 4 distinct dictionaries at all as the values - the 3 created initially and the fourth one that you add 100 times with keys 0-99.

This can be demonstrated with the `id()` function that returns distinct integer for each distinct object:

```
from collections import Counter

...

ids = [ id(i) for i in namelist.values() ]
print Counter(ids)
```

results in:

```
Counter({139830514626640: 100, 139830514505160: 1, 
    139830514504880: 1, 139830514505440: 1})
```

To get distinct dictionaries, you need to copy the default value:

```
namelist[i] = default_val.copy()
```

Or create a new dictionary on each loop

```
namelist[i] = {"age": 23, "region": 1}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.... I feel like a complete idiot right now for not having realised that! :|

Thanks again :D

Answer (score 2):

```
default_val={"age":23,"region":1}
for i in xrange(100):
    namelist[i]=default_val
```

This doesn't mean "set every entry to a dictionary with these particular age and region values". This means "set every entry to **this particular dictionary object**".

```
for index in namelist:
    x = random.randint(0, 2)
    namelist[index]['region']=x
```

Since every object in `namelist` is really the same dictionary, all modifications in this loop happen to the same dictionary, and the last value of `x` wipes the others.

Evaluating a dict literal creates a new dict; assignment does not. If you want to make a new dictionary each time, put the dict literal in the loop:

```
for i in xrange(100):
    namelist[i]={"age":23,"region":1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add this as a comment but the link is too long. As others have said you have just shared the reference to the dictionary, if you want to see the visualisation you can check it out on [Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import+random%0A%0A__author__+%3D+%27navin%27%0A%0Anamelist%3D%7B%0A%22person1%22%3A%7B%22age%22%3A23,%22region%22%3A1%7D,%0A%22person2%22%3A%7B%22age%22%3A24,%22region%22%3A2%7D,%0A%22person3%22%3A%7B%22age%22%3A25,%22region%22%3A0%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Adef+testfunction%28%29%3A%0A++++default_val%3D%7B%22age%22%3A23,%22region%22%3A1%7D%0A++++for+i+in+xrange%28100%29%3A%0A++++++++namelist%5Bi%5D%3Ddefault_val%0A++++for+index+in+namelist%3A%0A++++++++x+%3D+random.randint%280,+2%29%0A++++++++namelist%5Bindex%5D%5B%27region%27%5D%3Dx%0A%0A++++print+namelist%0A%0A%0Aif+__name__+%3D%3D+%22__main__%22+%3A%0A++++testfunction%28%29&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=0) it should help you grok what's happening.